# Multi colored faces while in object mode

Tags: faces

I downloaded this model as an .obj and it came with this alternate color for some of the faces. What is it and how can I remove it. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: if it's one object : switch to edit mode, select all, and press Ctrl+N

Comment: That is happening due to the inverted normals, that means that some faces are facing the wrong way, so for you to get rid of that just press (Ctrl - N) in edit mode while everything is selected.

Comment: I had a hunch that it was the normals. Thank you so much